# How to chain individual elements of list into one individual element in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have the following list

```
List1 =['4','0','1','k']
```

How do i make sure that individual elements are combined into one single entity?

Here is the desired output

```
List1 =['401k']
```

Comment: `print(["".join(List1)])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.join`:

```
List1 = [''.join(List1)]
```